# Visual Studio 2012 Login Default Setup

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there any documentation on the login pages created by visual studio 2012?

So far, i have the database created and by the registering the login has filled the database with tables and my user's login info.  Clearly only the email, username and password is stored in the DB and i will have to populate with a profile page for other user details.

How do i create a role so i can use the manage.aspx page? The code says to create a 'local'
password. Is this in a config or in the database?

Also, any tips on email authentication? The database seems to be setup for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no documentation on this, atleast none that I could find. This is the best fit:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/timlee/archive/2010/06/14/the-new-asp-net-default-web-template-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx

After you create the website application from the template, you can edit the entities, forms and database structure to add, modify or remove fields as per your requirements.